# MVC2: Assign a name to the form using Html.BeginForm()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am using the following method overload for the Html.BeginForm() method to create a form in my view:

public static MvcForm BeginRouteForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, RouteValueDictionary routeValues);

I would like to specify the form name. But I can't see any parameter that will allow me to do so.

Any work-around for this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the overload you need:

```
public static MvcForm BeginRouteForm(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string routeName,
    Object routeValues,
    FormMethod method,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460167.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WEB.MVC.HTML.FORMEXTENSIONS.BEGINROUTEFORM%29;k%28VS.OBJECTBROWSER%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V4.0%22%29&rd=true)

Comment: Thanks Zippy :) A similar overload with RouteValueDictionary can also be used. I've mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following overload can be used:

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, FormMethod method, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes);
```

by substituing null for actionName and controllerName and appropriate FormMethod.

e.g.
Instead of:

```
<% Html.BeginForm(Html.MyRouteValues(Model.MyFilterOptions, Model.MySortOptions, Model.Page)); %>
```

I am using:

```
<% Html.BeginForm(null, null, Html.MyRouteValues(Model.MyFilterOptions, Model.MySortOptions, Model.Page), FormMethod.Post, new { @name = "myForm" }); %>
```